# jQuery works on Edge but not Chrome or Firefox

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have been following a tutorial (https://www.superhi.com/blog/how-to-add-web-design-elements-that-fade-in-and-out-on-scroll) on how to make elements fade in on scroll and ended up this code:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">  
</head>

<body>
    <section>Section contents</section>
    <section>Section contents</section>
    <section>Section contents</section>
    <section>Section contents</section>
    <section>Section contents</section>
    <section>Section contents</section>
</body>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="fade.js"></script>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
section {
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 5% 10%;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(0, 20px);
    transition: all 1s;
}

section.visible {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on("scroll", function () {
  var pageTop = $(document).scrollTop()
  var pageBottom = pageTop + $(window).innerHeight()
  var tags = $("section")

  for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    var tag = tags[i]

    if ($(tag).position().top < pageBottom) {
      $(tag).addClass("visible")
    } else {
      $(tag).removeClass("visible")
    }
  }
})
```

I've hosted it here: [www.notewellpress.co.uk/tests/fade.htm](http://www.notewellpress.co.uk/tests/fade.htm)

This works how it should in the fiddle and in Edge but all the section elements are given the visible class on scroll in Chrome and Firefox.

If you could point out what I'm doing wrong it would be a big help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>It seems to work for me, but because the effect happens right at the very bottom of the page and the fade effect is so fast, it's hard to notice and might appear like the content was already there.</strike>

How about if you offset pageBottom so the effect happens further up the page? Something like this:

`if ($(tag).position().top < (pageBottom-200)) {`

**Edit:** Although the JQuery documentation suggests that $(window).innerHeight() should return the height of the viewport, it's actually returning the height of the entire document.

Using the browser's native window.innerHeight should give an accurate viewport height, so you want pageBottom to be assigned like this:

`var pageBottom = pageTop + window.innerHeight;`

**Edit II:** Upon investigation, the issue appears to be that you're missing the doctype declaration at the start of your page.

`<!doctype html>`

This is likely why it works in the fiddle but not on your page. Whatever method JQuery is using to return the height behind the scenes seems to work differently cross-browser. So a more reliable fix is to just add a doctype and then you should be able to use either your original code or the native method I mentioned above.

Comment: The effect is subtle, thanks for the suggestions!I was testing it by looking for the class being added to the sections in inspector. I've hosted it here and still seem to having the same problem : [link](http://www.notewellpress.co.uk/tests/fade.htm)

Comment: You're right, for some reason $(window).innerHeight() isn't giving me the viewport size as the documentation suggests, it's giving me the height of the entire page (including the off-screen portion) meaning the position of the content is always less than pageBottom. I'll update the answer in light of this.

Comment: Looks like the doctype is the issue. I've updated the answer again. Hopefully this fixes it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are all the semicolons missing? Also, this is very badly optimised code. `tags` should be defined outside the handler for instance. Instead of the for loop you can use jQuery's `.each`. To keep your code, I'd rewrite like such:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var win = $(window),
    tags = $("section");
    
  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
      var pageBottom = win.scrollTop() + win.innerHeight();
      tags.each(function(i, el) {
        var $el = $(el);
        if ($el.position().top < pageBottom) {
          $el.addClass("visible");
        } else {
          $el.removeClass("visible");
        }
      });
  });
});
```

```css
section {
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 5% 10%;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(0, 20px);
  transition: all 1s;
}

section.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc nec ullamcorper nisl, vitae aliquet massa. Ut ut lacus metus. Curabitur placerat lacus id posuere euismod. Quisque ullamcorper nunc at lectus pellentesque rhoncus. Mauris euismod tristique
  pulvinar. Vestibulum facilisis varius sapien non euismod. Nulla vitae accumsan diam.</section>
<section>Cras nec auctor libero, id finibus est. Ut faucibus consequat velit ac sodales. Phasellus pellentesque neque quis pellentesque feugiat. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Mauris mauris dolor, tincidunt sit amet ante eu, blandit
  suscipit neque. Etiam justo lectus, consequat non sem a, aliquet molestie velit. Sed tincidunt porta odio eget consectetur. In a risus in augue blandit lacinia. Donec ipsum dolor, hendrerit sed ante sit amet, interdum facilisis mauris. Suspendisse ex
  nulla, scelerisque id turpis nec, sodales fringilla est. Donec ac lectus in leo varius ornare id ornare justo. Vivamus dui est, tincidunt feugiat nibh quis, pellentesque ullamcorper arcu. Vivamus porttitor tortor vel lorem pharetra mattis.</section>
<section>Integer euismod risus mollis bibendum tincidunt. Nulla ac rhoncus augue. Cras ac imperdiet eros, sed suscipit tellus. Sed sed iaculis eros. Cras sit amet mi eros. Duis nec dignissim orci. Suspendisse hendrerit est cursus tristique semper. In a metus dapibus,
  venenatis erat posuere, tempus sapien. Nam id condimentum massa.</section>
<section>Fusce euismod ex velit, a aliquam velit tempor eu. Aenean ut sem dui. Sed pellentesque viverra nisl ac sollicitudin. Ut volutpat odio tincidunt sem mattis, eget maximus lectus dapibus. In vestibulum felis vel accumsan efficitur. Nulla sit amet libero
  tempus, laoreet turpis id, lacinia diam. Donec nec dolor eget tortor pretium ultrices. Vestibulum dapibus, felis in consectetur fringilla, ante lacus imperdiet tortor, vel interdum neque massa non erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
  elit. Integer molestie rutrum dignissim. Phasellus venenatis malesuada eros a viverra. Ut iaculis placerat urna at laoreet. Vivamus tincidunt malesuada justo, sit amet convallis ipsum. Vestibulum quis fringilla massa. In egestas ultrices lectus, et
  tempor odio iaculis at.</section>
<section>Nam ornare sem id leo bibendum egestas. Quisque vel leo eget dolor lobortis sagittis ac vel diam. Duis pharetra varius tempor. Aenean aliquet sem a felis tempus sagittis. Donec vitae enim faucibus, maximus orci id, consequat arcu. Nulla lorem lorem, semper
  volutpat efficitur a, pulvinar ut urna. Quisque nunc erat, iaculis non accumsan nec, luctus a libero. Praesent suscipit nibh nec ex ultricies porttitor. Etiam finibus purus eu aliquam sodales. Vivamus efficitur blandit tortor a maximus. Donec ex nisi,
  porttitor et nunc a, gravida suscipit dui.</section>
<section>Maecenas consequat ornare imperdiet. Nunc justo sapien, accumsan vitae ligula tincidunt, porttitor mollis tortor. Sed egestas faucibus sagittis. Aliquam ac augue sit amet odio pellentesque rutrum. Nulla facilisi. Aliquam elementum dui quam, eu viverra
  arcu eleifend sit amet. Suspendisse eget facilisis ante, at gravida magna. Vestibulum sed molestie mauris, a lacinia nibh. Vivamus eleifend commodo lorem, et facilisis odio interdum in. Curabitur feugiat placerat tristique.</section>
<section>Nunc eu tellus eu nibh dapibus ultricies ac sit amet leo. Cras varius metus eu arcu convallis efficitur. Nullam sem justo, ultricies vel neque sed, lobortis facilisis nulla. Cras in dui sollicitudin, vestibulum neque et, scelerisque felis. Nullam ornare
  molestie sapien, non semper urna sodales id. Proin aliquam gravida venenatis. Pellentesque pretium massa non risus dignissim, ut malesuada turpis fermentum. Maecenas porta, nisi sit amet maximus sollicitudin, ligula lorem dignissim nulla, at congue
  augue metus in libero. Sed at ligula sagittis, condimentum dui eu, lobortis dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin a sodales arcu. Pellentesque at enim quis sem fringilla aliquet. Nam hendrerit, mauris mattis auctor mattis,
  mi lectus malesuada ligula, et volutpat eros nisl in libero.</section>
<section>Nulla facilisi. Curabitur commodo malesuada purus fringilla rutrum. Proin sagittis convallis libero id gravida. Aliquam vestibulum tincidunt sapien, quis congue magna mollis non. Praesent fermentum enim ac elit sollicitudin, et aliquet elit venenatis.
  Etiam molestie in leo at volutpat. Vestibulum non felis non sapien ultricies feugiat et volutpat magna. Pellentesque tincidunt nibh leo, eget aliquam metus tincidunt at. Fusce malesuada nec tellus non mattis. Nam pulvinar interdum quam eget imperdiet.
  Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Maecenas vulputate porttitor arcu, vitae ornare neque efficitur quis. Duis fringilla massa id pulvinar iaculis. Nullam nec elit at dui ornare accumsan et eget
  sem.
</section>
<section>Vivamus cursus justo lectus, id feugiat est venenatis sit amet. Mauris aliquet lectus ut neque aliquet mollis sed ut sapien. Cras molestie felis vel odio egestas tristique. Donec vitae feugiat libero, sed eleifend eros. Donec bibendum interdum tristique.
  Etiam et nunc turpis. Aenean pretium erat eget lectus vestibulum scelerisque. Nunc ut nisi sit amet arcu pharetra iaculis. Pellentesque mollis convallis nunc, nec mollis ligula ultricies id. Pellentesque pharetra ut risus volutpat luctus. Aenean in
  magna nec nisl tempor lacinia eget id magna.</section>
<section>Nam at purus sed nibh auctor tempor sed tristique libero. Phasellus nec venenatis elit, nec venenatis ipsum. Pellentesque tincidunt ligula in nibh luctus, eget hendrerit erat fringilla. In suscipit aliquet lacus, condimentum pulvinar est pretium sed.
  Etiam iaculis, sapien eget posuere gravida, neque magna ornare magna, nec dignissim arcu metus eu erat. Nulla tellus magna, sollicitudin nec neque vitae, molestie mollis odio. Sed sit amet velit pretium, commodo quam eget, mollis dui. Etiam tempus orci
  sit amet dui ornare, in elementum lacus facilisis. In vel tincidunt tellus. Fusce a lectus non risus posuere rhoncus non eu neque. In metus libero, consequat quis magna et, sodales faucibus orci. Quisque erat ex, pretium ac turpis at, consectetur blandit
  ante. Cras ligula dui, auctor in dui nec, maximus convallis magna. Sed nunc felis, volutpat eu cursus id, suscipit eget massa. Sed mollis vitae orci dictum maximus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</section>
```

I think this works as you want?

But even then that just doesn't seem like a good idea: on *every* scroll (dozens of times per second probably) you go through ALL sections to check if they ought to be visible. Either use a throttle, or only check the element following the currently visible one, or the ones that are not visible yet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var win = $(window),
    tags = $("section");

  $(window).on("scroll", $.throttle(250, checkSectionVisiblity));

  function checkSectionVisiblity() {
    var pageBottom = win.scrollTop() + win.innerHeight();
    tags.each(function(i, el) {
      var $el = $(el);
      if ($el.position().top < pageBottom) {
        $el.addClass("visible");
      } else {
        $el.removeClass("visible");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
section {
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 5% 10%;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(0, 20px);
  transition: all 1s;
}

section.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-throttle-debounce/1.1/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js"></script>
<section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc nec ullamcorper nisl, vitae aliquet massa. Ut ut lacus metus. Curabitur placerat lacus id posuere euismod. Quisque ullamcorper nunc at lectus pellentesque rhoncus. Mauris euismod tristique
  pulvinar. Vestibulum facilisis varius sapien non euismod. Nulla vitae accumsan diam.</section>
<section>Cras nec auctor libero, id finibus est. Ut faucibus consequat velit ac sodales. Phasellus pellentesque neque quis pellentesque feugiat. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Mauris mauris dolor, tincidunt sit amet ante eu, blandit
  suscipit neque. Etiam justo lectus, consequat non sem a, aliquet molestie velit. Sed tincidunt porta odio eget consectetur. In a risus in augue blandit lacinia. Donec ipsum dolor, hendrerit sed ante sit amet, interdum facilisis mauris. Suspendisse ex
  nulla, scelerisque id turpis nec, sodales fringilla est. Donec ac lectus in leo varius ornare id ornare justo. Vivamus dui est, tincidunt feugiat nibh quis, pellentesque ullamcorper arcu. Vivamus porttitor tortor vel lorem pharetra mattis.</section>
<section>Integer euismod risus mollis bibendum tincidunt. Nulla ac rhoncus augue. Cras ac imperdiet eros, sed suscipit tellus. Sed sed iaculis eros. Cras sit amet mi eros. Duis nec dignissim orci. Suspendisse hendrerit est cursus tristique semper. In a metus dapibus,
  venenatis erat posuere, tempus sapien. Nam id condimentum massa.</section>
<section>Fusce euismod ex velit, a aliquam velit tempor eu. Aenean ut sem dui. Sed pellentesque viverra nisl ac sollicitudin. Ut volutpat odio tincidunt sem mattis, eget maximus lectus dapibus. In vestibulum felis vel accumsan efficitur. Nulla sit amet libero
  tempus, laoreet turpis id, lacinia diam. Donec nec dolor eget tortor pretium ultrices. Vestibulum dapibus, felis in consectetur fringilla, ante lacus imperdiet tortor, vel interdum neque massa non erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
  elit. Integer molestie rutrum dignissim. Phasellus venenatis malesuada eros a viverra. Ut iaculis placerat urna at laoreet. Vivamus tincidunt malesuada justo, sit amet convallis ipsum. Vestibulum quis fringilla massa. In egestas ultrices lectus, et
  tempor odio iaculis at.</section>
<section>Nam ornare sem id leo bibendum egestas. Quisque vel leo eget dolor lobortis sagittis ac vel diam. Duis pharetra varius tempor. Aenean aliquet sem a felis tempus sagittis. Donec vitae enim faucibus, maximus orci id, consequat arcu. Nulla lorem lorem, semper
  volutpat efficitur a, pulvinar ut urna. Quisque nunc erat, iaculis non accumsan nec, luctus a libero. Praesent suscipit nibh nec ex ultricies porttitor. Etiam finibus purus eu aliquam sodales. Vivamus efficitur blandit tortor a maximus. Donec ex nisi,
  porttitor et nunc a, gravida suscipit dui.</section>
<section>Maecenas consequat ornare imperdiet. Nunc justo sapien, accumsan vitae ligula tincidunt, porttitor mollis tortor. Sed egestas faucibus sagittis. Aliquam ac augue sit amet odio pellentesque rutrum. Nulla facilisi. Aliquam elementum dui quam, eu viverra
  arcu eleifend sit amet. Suspendisse eget facilisis ante, at gravida magna. Vestibulum sed molestie mauris, a lacinia nibh. Vivamus eleifend commodo lorem, et facilisis odio interdum in. Curabitur feugiat placerat tristique.</section>
<section>Nunc eu tellus eu nibh dapibus ultricies ac sit amet leo. Cras varius metus eu arcu convallis efficitur. Nullam sem justo, ultricies vel neque sed, lobortis facilisis nulla. Cras in dui sollicitudin, vestibulum neque et, scelerisque felis. Nullam ornare
  molestie sapien, non semper urna sodales id. Proin aliquam gravida venenatis. Pellentesque pretium massa non risus dignissim, ut malesuada turpis fermentum. Maecenas porta, nisi sit amet maximus sollicitudin, ligula lorem dignissim nulla, at congue
  augue metus in libero. Sed at ligula sagittis, condimentum dui eu, lobortis dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin a sodales arcu. Pellentesque at enim quis sem fringilla aliquet. Nam hendrerit, mauris mattis auctor mattis,
  mi lectus malesuada ligula, et volutpat eros nisl in libero.</section>
<section>Nulla facilisi. Curabitur commodo malesuada purus fringilla rutrum. Proin sagittis convallis libero id gravida. Aliquam vestibulum tincidunt sapien, quis congue magna mollis non. Praesent fermentum enim ac elit sollicitudin, et aliquet elit venenatis.
  Etiam molestie in leo at volutpat. Vestibulum non felis non sapien ultricies feugiat et volutpat magna. Pellentesque tincidunt nibh leo, eget aliquam metus tincidunt at. Fusce malesuada nec tellus non mattis. Nam pulvinar interdum quam eget imperdiet.
  Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Maecenas vulputate porttitor arcu, vitae ornare neque efficitur quis. Duis fringilla massa id pulvinar iaculis. Nullam nec elit at dui ornare accumsan et eget
  sem.
</section>
<section>Vivamus cursus justo lectus, id feugiat est venenatis sit amet. Mauris aliquet lectus ut neque aliquet mollis sed ut sapien. Cras molestie felis vel odio egestas tristique. Donec vitae feugiat libero, sed eleifend eros. Donec bibendum interdum tristique.
  Etiam et nunc turpis. Aenean pretium erat eget lectus vestibulum scelerisque. Nunc ut nisi sit amet arcu pharetra iaculis. Pellentesque mollis convallis nunc, nec mollis ligula ultricies id. Pellentesque pharetra ut risus volutpat luctus. Aenean in
  magna nec nisl tempor lacinia eget id magna.</section>
<section>Nam at purus sed nibh auctor tempor sed tristique libero. Phasellus nec venenatis elit, nec venenatis ipsum. Pellentesque tincidunt ligula in nibh luctus, eget hendrerit erat fringilla. In suscipit aliquet lacus, condimentum pulvinar est pretium sed.
  Etiam iaculis, sapien eget posuere gravida, neque magna ornare magna, nec dignissim arcu metus eu erat. Nulla tellus magna, sollicitudin nec neque vitae, molestie mollis odio. Sed sit amet velit pretium, commodo quam eget, mollis dui. Etiam tempus orci
  sit amet dui ornare, in elementum lacus facilisis. In vel tincidunt tellus. Fusce a lectus non risus posuere rhoncus non eu neque. In metus libero, consequat quis magna et, sodales faucibus orci. Quisque erat ex, pretium ac turpis at, consectetur blandit
  ante. Cras ligula dui, auctor in dui nec, maximus convallis magna. Sed nunc felis, volutpat eu cursus id, suscipit eget massa. Sed mollis vitae orci dictum maximus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</section>
```